# ¿Hay diferencias entre un entorno linux / windows para programar php + mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows

Tengo un programa que está en PHP instalado en LINUX  y debo agregar unas nuevas cosas. No lo hice yo y quiero montarlo en un ambiente de pruebas en windows.

Con Xampp levante el servidor Apache y MySql (he tenido unos problemillas de conexión a la base de datos pero eso lo coloque en otro foro) la pregunta es: ¿en mi ambiente de pruebas en windows habrá comandos de php que me cambien? o ¿cuál seria la mejor manera de realizar el ambiente de pruebas?

Comment: Yo suelo trabajar con Xampp y en general no tendrás problemas, pero sí pueden existir algunas diferencias. Por ejemplo, aunque PHP no soporta nativamente programación multihilo,  hay una extensión para simularla y esta NO funciona en Windows.
Si quieres estar seguro (y tu equipo tiene recursos suficientes) virtualiza un entorno Linux, p.e. VirtualBox + Vagrant Homestead. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias voy a probar la virtualizacion